# Python - How to copy to a list specific attributes in a list of class objects?

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, copy

I define a class, containing a few attributes

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, attr1_in, attr2_in, attr3_in):
         self.attr1 = attr1_in
         self.attr2 = attr2_in
         self.attr3 = attr3_in
```

Then I declare a list, initialize some objects of this class, and add it to the list

```
class_objs = []
i = 0
while i < 10:
    newObj = myClass(newObj, i, i+1, i+2)
    class_objs.append(newObj)
    i += 1
```

My question is, how can I then create a list, of say attr2 for every object in that list?
I know I could iterate through the `class_objs` list, but is there an easier way?

I'm hoping for some type of built-in function, or one-liner code.

Running Python 3.7.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a list comprehension for all of it.

Once your class is defined, this is how you would create multiple objects (let's say 10):

```
objects = [myClass(i, i+1, i+2) for i in range(10)]
```

And here's how you can collect all of `attr2` from them:

```
attributes = [obj.attr2 for obj in objects]
```

[Read more about list comprehension here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)